# Facebook API : get user likes other than Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build an app that needs to get what a facebook user likes. By "likes" I mean not only which facebook pages the user is following, but also all likes related to posts, photos, or non facebook urls.

All I've found in the API doc is this endpoint:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes

Unfortunately, it only returns facebook pages a user likes. Is there a way to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: Did you finally find what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve what you are doing using Graph API v2.0 and above.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of, thx for the confirmation. Is there any reason for that?